# How to create a responsive div container with text and thumbnail image carousel on the left size and an image slider on the right side?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider, responsive

I have a problem creating this type of hero section: [Design I need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NgzK.jpg)

The essential problem is to make text, carousel, and slider responsive, and on mobile, they will be one under the other. And they won't change their height (because the images all have different heights).

Another problem is that the div of the slider is divided into 2 other divs: one for the text and another for the image itself, and I can't make it look like on design image I have.

What I have tried is this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="../IMAGES/1.jpeg" alt="Thumbnail 1"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="../IMAGES/2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="../IMAGES/2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="../IMAGES/2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2"></div>
                <!-- Add more carousel items as needed -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
              <button class="control-btn" onclick="prevSlide()">❮</button>
              <button class="control-btn" onclick="nextSlide()">❯</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="slide-text">
                    <h3>Title 1</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                  </div>
              <img src="../IMAGES/1.jpeg" alt="Slide 1">
            </div>
            <!-- Add more slides as needed -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 90vh;
  }

  .left-side {
    width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .left-side h2 {
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  .left-side p{
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .carousel-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .carousel {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .carousel-inner {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .carousel-item {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
    height: 110px;

  }

  .carousel-item img {
    height: 107px;
    width: auto;
  }

  .controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .control-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
  }

  .right-side {
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .slider {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }

  .slide {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
.slide-text{
    flex: 1;
    width: 30%;
    justify-content: left;

}
  .slide img {
    flex: 1;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Is this practice or for a piece of work? There are many packages out there, that will make your life easier for implementing a carousel such as glide.js or swiper.js.

With regards mobile styling, you've made a good start with flexbox, have a play with flex-wrap as well as using media queries to stack elements on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to achieve the design I needed, I used a carousel Glide.js:

```
<div class="carousel">
                <div class="glide">
                    <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                      <ul class="glide__slides">
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/5.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="glide__slide"><img src="IMAGES/6.jpg" alt=""></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
                        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
                        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And of course added some options that you can find on glide.js documentation.

For a big slider, I just played with flex properties and positioning relative to achieve a responsive design.